# How to emplace_back a string vector to a vector of struct type?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

My header file contains a structure as shown:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Fields {
  std::string f_name, l_name, id;
  Fields (std::string fn,
          std::string ln,
          std::string i): f_name{fn},
    l_name{ln}, id{i} {
  }
};
```

and the main program contains a string vector "values" which actually contains strings extracted from a file

```
#include "my_header.h"

int main() {

   std::vector <std::string> values = {"xyz", "p", "30"}; //have given values to it as example
   static vector<Fields> field_values;
   for (uint32_t vl=0; vl<values.size(); vl++){
     field_values.emplace_back(values[vl]);

   }

return 0;
}
```

But the above code gives an error:

> **error**: no matching function for call to
>   ‘Fields::Fields(std::basic_string&)’   { ::new((void *)__p)
>   _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
>       ^

whereas when I give the individual values to emplace_back without using a for-loop, there is no error

```
field_values.emplace_back(values[0], values[1], values[2]); //gives no error
```

How can I emplace_back the values one at a time as in my code?

Comment: Your constructor for Field takes three parameters - you either have to create a constructor that only takes a single parameter, or you have to fix the way you're trying to emplace the string values.

Comment: you are supplying references to `std::string`s as parameters to the `Fields` constructor, when your definition for the `Fields` constructor takes in actual `std::string`s. Try altering the definition of the `Fields` constructor to `Fields (std::string & fn, std::string & ln, std::string & i)`

Answer (score 1):

`Fields`'s constructor takes 3 parameters. Your call to `emplace_back` provides one. `emplace` doesn't magically know you're going to provide more parameters *later*. It construct the object from the parameters you provide in that call.

You cannot do what you're trying to do: loop over elements of a container and pass those elements as a sequence of constructor parameters. Or at least, you can't do it with a `for` loop.

You *can* employ some metaprogramming and C++14 gymnastics, using `std::index_sequence`:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename U, size_t ...Ints>
void emplace_from_params(T &t, const U &u, std::index_sequence<Ints...>)
{
  t.emplace_back(u[Ints]...);
}

int main()
{
   std::vector <std::string> values = {"xyz", "p", "30"}; //have given values to it as example
   vector<Fields> field_values;

   emplace_from_params(field_values, values, std::make_index_sequence<3>{});
}
```

However, this is static. You cannot do this by dynamically passing `values.size()` to `make_index_sequence`.